# Fluent NHibernate - ORA-00904: : invalid identifier Since Object property name is an oracle key word

Tags: nhibernate, fluent, ora-00904

I have used Fluent NHibernate to auto map for Oracle database. My Domain class have some Oracle key words as property names. Example: Group is a key word in Oracle. When we use Group as a column the it needs to be enclosed within quotes (like "Group"). How can we take care of this in Fluent NHibernate?

I have modified the IColumnInstances to add ColumnName method and added a Convention. After adding this code it is throwing another error "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis". Is there any alternate solution?

Here is the code

```
public class ColumnNameConvention : IColumnConvention
{
    public void Apply(IColumnInstance instance)
    {
        try
        {
            if (instance.Name.Length > 30)
            {
                instance.ColumnName(instance.Name.Substring(instance.Name.Length - 25, 25));
            }
            else
            {
                instance.ColumnName("\"" + instance.Name + "\"");
            }
            instance.Length(200);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct *magic* sign to be used in your case is:    `
*(see below example for better understanding)*

Check it here:

- [DB Column named “Order” with Fluent NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/484399/1679310)
- [Fluent NHibernate Column Mapping with Reserved Word](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2879630/1679310)

Example:

```
Map(x => x.Group).Column("`Group`");
```

Interesting reading for a global settings:

- [SchemaMetadataUpdater.QuoteTableAndColumns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2442839/1679310)
- [NHibernate: forcing square brackets in schema export?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105924/1679310)

example:

```
FluentConfiguration configuration = ...

configuration
 .ExposeConfiguration(x => x.SetProperty("hbm2ddl.keywords", "auto-quote"));

return configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
```

or

```
SchemaMetadataUpdater.QuoteTableAndColumns(config)
```

Comment: Great to see that! Nhibernate is powerful tool...;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code.

```
private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
    {
        try
        {
            var cfg = OracleClientConfiguration.Oracle10.ConnectionString(c =>
            c.Is("Data Source=XXXXXXX;User ID=XXXXX;Password=XXXX;"));

            FluentConfiguration configuration = Fluently.Configure()
                    .Database(cfg)
                    .Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings.Add(CreateAutomappings))
                    .ExposeConfiguration(x => x.SetProperty("hbm2ddl.keywords", "auto-quote"))
                    .ExposeConfiguration(BuildSchema);

            return configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.Message);
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Remember.. You still need to limit the column length to 30 characters. I have modified the IColumnInstances to add ColumnName method and added a Convention. Here is the code for that

Add this code in ColumnInstance class of FluentNHibernate. I have also added the respective interface methods.

```
 public void ColumnName(string columnname)
    {
        mapping.Set(x => x.Name, Layer.Conventions, columnname);
    }
```

Add this implementation code in your code.

```
public class ColumnNameConvention : IColumnConvention, IColumnConventionAcceptance
{
    public void Accept(IAcceptanceCriteria<IColumnInspector> criteria)
    {
        criteria.Expect(x => x.Name.Length > 30);
    }

    public void Apply(IColumnInstance instance)
    {
        try
        {
            instance.ColumnName(instance.Name.Substring(instance.Name.Length - 25, 25));
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```